# Dual boot alternatives

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I would like to clean install a Linux distribution as Ubuntu etc. My laptop runs Windows 8.1.

I have two options in mind. Clean install or dual boot.

My technical question is: My laptop have a 8GB SSD drive, which it uses to boot Windows with and a 500GB for storage. I wonder what that 8GB SSD stores? It can't store the whole Windows install as that would be much more than 8GB. Also if I would do a clean install of Ubuntu could I use the 8GB SSD to have Ubuntu boot up quicker. How would I install it? Option two, if I would like to dual boot, how would I proceed having the SSD to boot both systems?

I also wish to ask about the Legacy and UEFI differences. Windows runs with UEFI. So when I'm installing Linux, should I run Legacy, and if I dual boot, what option to I choose?

Answer (score 0):

You can dual boot your laptop with *Windows 8.1* and *Ubuntu*. As I do in my desktop. I think you don't need to format your Windows from SSD device. Just free up 8GB space from your 500GB HDD using "**Windows Disk Manager**" from "**Control Panel**". Insert Ubuntu boot media such as a Live CD/DVD or a bootable pen drive, run "**wubi**", click on "**Full Demo**" and restart. When Ubuntu is booted up choose "**Install Ubuntu**" and then "**Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8**" and complete setup. Now you have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on your laptop. Choose what you want from bootloader menu. Enjoy Linux!

**P.S.** *Removing Windows from SSD can harm your Computer such as preventing a OS from booting. But I'm not sure that it could prevent Ubuntu from booting even after a fresh/clean install*.